# Looking up in a List

Tags: groovy

I wrote this simple code

```
​def x = [[a: 1], [a: 2], [a: 3]] 
if (x["foo"]) {
    print("Hello")
}​​​​​​
```

​
My expected output was that Hello will not be printed because x does not contain "foo".

However the output of `x["foo"]` is `[null, null, null]` which is not null and it still enters the if condition.

So how can I check if object x does not contain a property called foo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test if it does contain such key you can use

```
x*.containsKey("foo").any{it}
```

Here `*.` means to apply the following method to all items in the list, so

```
x*.containsKey("foo")
```

returns

```
[false,false,false]
```

Next `.any{it}` applies the closure to each of these and checks if any of them result in true.  In your case, it returns false.

---

Equivalently, we could have done

```
x.any{it.containsKey("foo")}
```

Note that by default, the closure uses a variable `it`.

In your case, the choice between the two doesn't really matter.  For a long list, this form is probably better, as the `any` method can bail out early if it sees a true value and avoid checking all maps in the list.  The first form does not have that luxury (it may be possible for the compiler to optimize them to be the same, but I don't know if that happens or not).

---

Therefore, we can rewrite your conditional as

```
if (x.any{it.containsKey("foo")}) {
    print("Hello")
}
```

or

```
if (x*.containsKey("foo").any{it}) {
    print("Hello")
}
```